# Application/octet-stream filling last row of file with NULL after downloading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, download

I'm trying to download a `.hex` file from server and save it on the user machine. The file size is a little above 2.4 MB. After the download on the user machine, it gets to 4 MB. The additional size comes from that the last line gets filled with NULL. The NULL count is exactly as the rows in the file - 50 rows => 50 NULLs at the end (in my case 32898 rows(lines) => 32898 NULLs at the end).

I tried removing them but with no luck. Is there a way to do this in the current method? Alternative ways of the method with FileResult are also welcomed.

```
public FileResult Download(string documentID) {

    byte[] buffer = null;

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\Temp\\temp\\" + documentID + ".hex", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)) {
        buffer = new byte[fs.Length - fs.Position];
        fs.Read(buffer, 0, (int)fs.Length);
    }

    var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition {
        FileName = "HEX_FILE_NAME.hex",
        Inline = false,
    };
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
    return File(buffer, "application/octet-stream");
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of headbanging I managed to find solution to my problem. The file gets downloaded and there is no additional NULL row anymore. Tested it on a live server also. Works for other file extentions as well. I'll leave the solution here in case it helps someone in the future.

```
public FileResult Download(string documentID) {

            string fileName = @"C:\\Temp\\temp\\" + documentID + ".hex";
            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fileName);

            if (fileInfo.Exists) {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileInfo.Name);
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileInfo.Length.ToString());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.TransmitFile(fileInfo.FullName);
                Response.End();
            }

            return File(fileName, "application/octet-stream");
        }
```